# 403 Forbidden on local Google Cloud Storage call

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using the default bucket name, but whenever I try to write a file, I get a `403 Forbidden`. It tries to write to a bucket named: `app_default_bucket`.

This is the default bucket retrieved by `file.DefaultBucketName(ctx)`.

Local file permissions also seem to be okay.

In production everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to write on your remote Google Cloud Storage account. Seems like a current bug. For now you might have to create/reconfigure the default bucket on your account.

[Using the client library with the dev server not working in Go](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12883)